# Return rows that have similar values in one column

Tags: mysql, sql

I need some assistance with returning rows that have common values in one of the columns. The data format is as follows:

Table (People) - Names of all Participant

```
* ID * Name      *
------------------
* 1  * Alice     *
* 2  * Bruce     *
* 3  * Charlie   *
* 4  * Dan       *
* 5  * Eric      *
* 6  * Fannie    *
```

Table (List) - List of Attendees for each Event

```
* Txn * Event_ID * ID *
-----------------------
* T1  * A        * 1 *
* T2  * A        * 2 *
* T3  * A        * 3 *
* T4  * A        * 4 *
* T5  * B        * 1 *
* T6  * B        * 2 *
* T7  * B        * 5 *
* T8  * B        * 6 *
```

I would like to find out (i) if any two individuals have met each other before, and if so, (ii) at which event. In this case, I'm interested to find out whether Participant 1 and Participant 2 have met before, the desired outcome:

```
* Event_ID *  ID *  Name  * Txn *
---------------------------------
* A        *  1  *  Alice * T1  *
* A        *  2  *  Bruce * T2  *
* B        *  1  *  Alice * T5  *
* B        *  2  *  Bruce * T6  *
```

This is the code I have come up with thus far:

```
SELECT EVENT_ID, Txn
FROM People
JOIN List ON People.ID=List.ID
WHERE (List.ID=1 OR List.ID=2)
Group BY TXN, EVENT_ID
```

It currently only returns all the events attended by Participant 1 and Participant 2. I think I need to do a further sorting by group and count, but am unsure how it should be incorporated into the code.

```
GROUP BY EVENT_ID, HAVING COUNT (EVENT_ID)>1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need grouping at all, you just have to join the table to itself.

```
SELECT
*
FROM list l1
JOIN list l2 ON l1.ID != l2.ID AND l1.Event_ID = l2.Event_ID
WHERE
1 IN (l1.ID, l2.ID)
AND 2 IN (l1.ID, l2.ID)
```

- see it working here in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e650bc/2/0)

Comment: Thanks. I modified your responses slightly to get the output format I wanted. 

[link]https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xm48XeUkTdxp8SM8mL947n/0

Small issue I have is not being able to arrange the output columns in the order I desire (as above).

Comment: This may be an issue of the frontend. Anyway, order of columns shouldn't be of concern. Your code reads the result and cares about the presentation. A database shouldn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to know this for two people, you could alternatively return a single row with the two people on it. Of course this doesn't scale well if you want to expand to more people:

```
select
  a1.Event_ID,
  a1.Txn as Txn1,
  a2.Txn as Txn2,
  p1.ID as ID1,
  p1.Name as Name1,
  p2.ID as ID2,
  p2.Name as Name2
from
  List a1
  inner join List a2 
    on a2.Event_ID = a1.Event_ID
    and a2.Id <> a1.Id
  inner join People p1 on p1.ID = a1.ID
  inner join People p2 on p2.ID = a2.ID
where
  p1.ID = 1 and p2.ID = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i just had the idea that maybe you are looking for events where people met each other, i.e., not events where there was only a single person (which was the flaw in my previous code, see below). This works to find only events where two people attended:

```
select l.event_id, p.id as person_id, p.name as person_name, l.txn as txn_id
from people p
inner join list l
on p.id=l.person_id
inner join 
(
 select event_id, count(*) as headcount
 from list
 group by event_id
) x
on l.event_id=x.event_id
where x.headcount > 1
group by l.event_id, p.id, p.name
```

---

### Old answer

I think you need this:

```
select l.event_id, p.id as person_id, p.name as person_name, l.txn as txn_id 
from people p
inner join list l
on p.id=l.person_id
group by l.event_id, p.id, p.name
```

Result:

```
# event_id, person_id, person_name, txn_id
'A', '1', 'Alice', 'T1'
'A', '2', 'Bruce', 'T2'
'A', '3', 'Charlie', 'T3'
'A', '4', 'Dan', 'T4'
'B', '1', 'Alice', 'T5'
'B', '2', 'Bruce', 'T6'
'B', '5', 'Eric', 'T7'
'B', '6', 'Fannie', 'T8'
```

I have used the column name as 'person_id' in the list table to avoid confusion with the 'id' column in the person table. Also, i suppose id is the primary key and the auto id in the list table and 'person_id' here is the foreign key referencing id from the person table.

Comment: Would it be possible to show the workings on SQLfiddle? Not terribly familiar with the various notations

Comment: updated one: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qzbg9GJ8q5riehPwYfpY2n/4#&togetherjs=98heyS9MqS

Answer (score -1):

Based on the various responses, the following code is the closest to what I was looking for.

Only small issue is that I could not get the output columns in the order i was originally looking for. Minor inconvenience.

```
SELECT l1.Event_ID, l1.ID, p.Name, l1.Txn
FROM list l1
JOIN list l2 ON l1.ID != l2.ID AND l1.Event_ID = l2.Event_ID
JOIN people p ON l1.ID = p.ID
WHERE
1 IN (l1.ID, l2.ID)
AND 2 IN (l1.ID, l2.ID)
ORDER BY l1.Event_ID, l1.ID;
```

See code working on [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xm48XeUkTdxp8SM8mL947n/0)